# Use plain javascript method on jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a jQuery object, and I wish to call a plain JavaScript method on it:

```
alert( $('#myInput').tagName );
```

Or

```
alert( $('#myInput').id );
```

Is there a general principle for calling a JS method on a jQ object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.get(#)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$('#myInput').get(0).tagName
```

or add an array index

```
$('#myInput')[0].tagName
```

As an aside: it is preferred to use `nodeName` over `tagName`.